# Dbcontext scaffold .Net Core 2.1 generates arithmetic overlow

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

**The table:**
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test1]( [test1] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([test1] ASC)

**The command :**
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=tcp:db-sql-370,33416\;Initial Catalog=GISPROCESS;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkC
ore.SqlServer -o Models -t test1 --schema dbo

**The error:**
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.

*I can post the full stack trace, but thought I would start with this.*

Answer (score 0):

Can't repro.  Run this from an empty directory:

```
rm * 

$sql = @"
drop table if exists test1;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test1]
( 
  [test1] [int] NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_test1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([test1] ASC) 
)
"@

Invoke-Sqlcmd -server . -database tempdb -Query $sql

dotnet new console -n test

$proj = @"
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
"@

$proj | out-file -FilePath test.csproj 

dotnet restore

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t test1 --schema dbo

type Models\test1.cs
```

Comment: Thanks.  I followed your steps with changes only to server and database (I don't have create access in tempdb).  Same error (arithmetic overflow).  We are on Sql Server 2014 - could that be the issue?

Comment: Unlikely SQL 2014 is the problem.  Next try SQL Profiler and capture the statement causing the error.